# webview on all android os?

Tags: java, android, webview

Getting an error with my webview code. Wanting to create a webview that would work on all android OS. Am i on the right path?

webview1 seems to be giving me trouble. Not sure exactly why. Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

main.java

```
package com.webapp.Area;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    String url = "http://www.area.com;";
    WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webview1);

    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl(url);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

  }
```

activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[This is what im staring at. :/](http://s8.postimg.org/8lopt6bp1/code.png)

Comment: Can you plz post your logcat error log related to webview?

Comment: It won't let me even run it because webview is giving the error. It is  saying that it is not resolved or is not a field. Anything else i can post to help get a better understanding?

Comment: Maybe its not relevant with your error but there is an extra semicolon in your url variable.

Comment: Thanks, but yeah got rid of it just now and it's still giving me that error that webview1 isn't resolved. Is there anything else i can post to give a better idea?

Posted an image so you could see what i see.

Comment: Did you try to clean and build your project? Maybe you did not save your xml file.

Comment: Got it, yeah you were right about saving it all. and got rid of the small stuff, also how can i make it open links only in webview?

Answer (score 0):

:)  just need to change below line.

```
WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webview1); 

to

WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1); // "V" should be in capital
```

Comment: Still getting the same error, appreciate it. Anything else you can think of?

Posted an image of what im looking at.